# Before and after icon for Accordion menu on website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to use the code from [this source](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion_symbol) to add an accordian menu to my website. Everything works, except for the + and - icons that signify the menu being open or closed. [On my site, the icons appear below the words.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9pu6.png)

How can I get the icons to appear centered to the left of the words, like they do in the original source code?

*Edit*
Sorry, I thought the link to the source code was good enough since I just copied and pasted it to my site.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
     panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
     panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + 'px';
    } 
  }
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="subsection_title"> Baby Sleeping Tips By Timeframe</h1>
<p>
Here are suggestions that most parents agree are worth trying during each phase:
</p>
<button class="accordion"><b>From 0 To 2 Months</b><br><p class="small"> Babies sleep regularly and often for the first couple of weeks. Put them down to sleep when you start to see the first signs of drowsiness (like drooping eyelids or some fussiness).
</p></button>
```

Comment: Added the code I'm using on the site

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
```

to `button.accordion`, and

```
position: absolute;
right: 5px;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
transform: translateY(50%);
```

to `button.accordion:after`.

Working example:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
     panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
     panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + 'px';
    } 
  }
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: translateY(50%);
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="subsection_title"> Baby Sleeping Tips By Timeframe</h1>
<p>
Here are suggestions that most parents agree are worth trying during each phase:
</p>
<button class="accordion"><b>From 0 To 2 Months</b><br><p class="small"> Babies sleep regularly and often for the first couple of weeks. Put them down to sleep when you start to see the first signs of drowsiness (like drooping eyelids or some fussiness).
</p></button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is great!